# Why my query shows parent key violation? even after I have filled correc data

Tags: sql

```
create table  s38
(
 sno number(5) primary key,
 sname varchar(10),
 city varchar(10)
);
create table  p38
(
 pno number(5) primary key,
 pname varchar(10),
 color varchar(10)
);
create table  j38
(
 jno number(5) primary key,
 jname varchar(10),
 city varchar(10)
);
create table spj38
(
 primary key (sno,pno,jno) ,
 qty number(5),
  sno references s38(sno),
 pno references p38(pno) ,
 jno references j38(jno)   
);

table data:
s38:
1 ayush patiala
2 pankaj indore

p38:
1 nut gray
2 hammer black

j38:
1 mining bhopal
2 super pune
 spj38:
1,1,1,100
```

I have created these four table but when I insert data into spj38, it displays parent key violation error, why?
I have maintained foreign key constraint.

Comment: what data you are trying to insert in spj38?

Comment: shouldnt it be spj38:100,1,1,1 ?

Comment: Can you post your insert statement

Answer (score 0):

Only reason for primary key violation is that you are adding same value in the primary key column. In your case `sno, pno, jno` are the composite keys

Also when you have applied foreign key constraint on the table the key you are adding must
 be present in the parent table so the values which you are trying to add in your insert query must be present in the parent table.

Once you have added 1,1,1,100 in the table you cannot add the same composite key again which in your case will be 1,1,100.

Hope this helps